# ARM legV8 Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault

Tags: gcc, assembly, segmentation-fault, arm, armv8

I have recently wrote this code in assembly (ARM legV8) which uses recursion to calculate gcd between 64 bit random numbers. In the first place i generate 2 random numbers using random() and then i check if the are relatively prime ( gcd(num1,num2) == 1). If not then generate new numbers. Repeat until  relatively prime numbers are found. The random() and gcd() functions are working fine (checked). I have an issue with the stack (Segmentation fault) when i try to store on it an updated value. I get error on the third time i call the loop on that line **str     x22,[x29,24]**  Here is my code :

```
        .data                                   //Start of the datasegment
q_initialState:         .string "Please enter the intial state : "
scanner_hex:            .string "%p"
output_num:             .string "%llu\n"
gcd_result:             .string "GCD is : %d\n"
message:                .string "They are prime numbers \n"
.text                                   //Start of the .text segment
    .global main
main:
    stp     x29,x30,[sp,-32]!               
    add     x29,sp,0 

    adr     x0,q_initialState             
    bl      printf   

    add     x1,x29,28
    adr     x0,scanner_hex                  
    bl      scanf 

    ldr     x19,[x29,28]                   //this is the initial state
loop: 

    mov     x2,x19                                                 
    bl      random 
    mov     x22,x5 
    mov     x1,x22
    adr     x0,output_num
    bl      printf  

    mov     x2,x19                          
    bl      random 
    mov     x23,x5
    mov     x1,x23
    adr     x0,output_num
    bl      printf

    str     x22,[x29,24]         // <----------- ERROR HERE ---------
    str     x23,[x29,28]    

    bl      gcd 
    cmp     x24,1
    bne     loop

    ldp     x29,x30,[sp],32
    ret

random:                                    
    stp     x29,x30,[sp,-32]!              
    add     x29,sp,0         

    eor     x2,x2,x2,lsr 12                  
    eor     x2,x2,x2,lsl 25                
    eor     x2,x2,x2,lsr 27  
    ldr     x4,=0x2545f4914f6cdd1d  
    mul     x5,x2,x4 

    mov     x19,x2

    ldp     x29,x30,[sp],32                 
    ret

gcd:
    stp     x29,x30,[sp,-32]!
    add     x29,sp,0

    ldr     x9,[x29,56]             //Value for variable m
    ldr     x10,[x29,60]            //Value for variable n

    udiv    x11,x9,x10                 
    mul     x11,x11,x10
    sub     x1,x9,x11   

    cbz     x1,return_n
    str     x10,[x29,24]
    str     x1,[x29,28]
    bl      gcd

    ldp     x29,x30,[sp],32
    ret

return_n:
    ldr     x1,[x29,60]
    mov     x24,x1
    ldp     x29,x30,[sp],32
    ret
```

Comment: Means your `x29` is out of range, possibly stack overflow. Use your debugger. Also, comment your code, especially if you want others to help.

Comment: I copied your code, entered "1" for state and it returns without a seg fault. What are your inputs that result in a seg fault?

Comment: Ok - I now see that entering 2 results in a seg fault.

Comment: Seems like you have some stack corruption. If you enter bt (backtrace) in gdb after the seg fault, you'll see something like "Backtrace stopped: previous frame identical to this frame (corrupt stack?)". After returning from your gdc func, x29 is pointing to a mem address that is not accessible.  E.g., Cannot access memory at address 0x7f0352a912 . So you need to review how you are handling saving/restoring x29, x30, among other things. You may also encounter bus errors. You should consider doing gdc w/ subtraction vs udiv.

Comment: @InfinitelyManic Thank you for your response. I enter a hexadecimal value = 0x123456789ABCDEF. Thank you for your support about gcc. I will try it again!

Comment: Here is some ARM documentation to GCD with less instructions http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.den0024a/ch08s02s01.html

Comment: @InfinitelyManic I have solved the issue. It was the size of each number in the stack. Because the random numbers generated ware 64 bit i had to use 8 bytes for storing each one. I found your debugging advises very helpful Thanks a lot.